# Why does Flask redirect me to the index?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

When I give the submit button it does not verify it does not enter the if of the "POST" request and the `login_form.validate()`.

I try to learn but I have already been trying to solve this for 5 hours, I no longer know what to do.

```py
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():

    login_form = forms.logger(request.form)
    title = 'Gamework'
    
    #imprimira los datos en la consola si el metodos es post y los datos son validos
    if request.method == 'POST' and login_form.validate():
        print('Hola mundo')
        email = login_form.email.data
        
        password = login_form.password.data
         
        user = User.query.filter_by(email = email).first()

        if user is not None and user.verify_password(password):
            print('test 2')
            succes_menssage = 'Se ha iniciado correctamente {}'.format(email)
            
            flash(succes_menssage)
            session['Email'] = email
            return redirect( url_for('index') )
   
    
    return render_template('logger_user.html', title = title, form = login_form)
```

Here I show the `Models.py`. When I enter the login function to verify the post request and the validation of the form, it only sends me the JSON and does nothing, it just stays in the same directory instead of going to the.

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
import datetime
db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(40))
    password = db.Column(db.String(256))
    create_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.datetime.now)
    
    def __init__(self, username, email, password):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = self.__create_password(password)
    
    def __create_password(self, password):
        return generate_password_hash(password)
    def verify_password(self, password):
        r = check_password_hash(self.password, password)
        print(r)
    
        return r
```

What could it be? This is the page:

[image: this is the page]

Comment: If you can't get it to meet the criteria of the `if` clause, either it's not a POST request, or the form isn't validating, so you need to check which condition(s) are failing. _I.e._, either use a debugger in your IDE to see the state of the`request` and the `login_form` objects, or use strategically-placed `print` calls to do so; _e.g._, `print(str(login_form))`

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information here to debug your issue fully -- but in terms of how you can continue your investigation;

- Are you sure you're making a POST request?

  - Add `print(request.method)` outside of your `if` statement.
- Is your call to `login_form.validate()` returning `True`? I'd guess not.

  - You can debug this by adding `print(login_form.validate())`, and if that returns `False`, checking the contents of `login_form.errors` ([docs here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.errors)). That will contain info on why exactly validation is failing. How to proceed will be dependent on that.

Comment: In theory the login_form should be false until the moment it is full (when doing the verification that I recommend login_form.errors did not throw anything) the print (request.method) outside the if it threw me a GET